# Split a string by whitespace but retain \n - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby file that reads files and splits the text into an array using `split(' ')`. The problem is that these text files contain newline characters, and I would like to retain those newline characters. For example, if I run the following code

```
"Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet".split(' ')
```

I get the output of

```
["Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

Why does split remove the newline character? How can i retain `\n` in my array?

Comment: Using `' '` (a string with a single space) is special, likely with roots from Perl. This "magic" *should* be covered in the documentation - so consult there first. Note how the special nature is the *string* `" "`, and not the *regular expression* `/ +/`.

Comment: _If pattern is a single space, str is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored._ http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Michael Berkowski's comment on your question is correct.

If you want to work around this case, use a regular expression:

```
"Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet".split(/ /)
#=> ["Lorem", "ipsum\ndolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

Comment: @oldergod `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f]`.

Answer (score 0):

Further iterating on Ryan Bigg's answer; Looks like you can use Regex with capture groups to specifically retain newlines.

```
"Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit amet".split(/ |([\t\r\n\f])/)
=> ["Lorem", "ipsum", "\n", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

Inspired by yonosoytu's comment in [String#split](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split)